# Raspberry With Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi connected to a 2x16 LCD and a numpad. My problem is that I can’t see the numbers am typing unless I hit enter. Any solution of how I can make it possible to type the number and it gets displayed? I have tried curses and threading but no luck
emphasized text

```
import lcddriver
display = lcddriver.lcd()

try:
    display.lcd_display_string('Room Number:',1)
    room = input()
    display.lcd_display_string(str(room),2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    display.lcd_clear()
```

Comment: Please explain what application you are typing numbers into? If it's your own code, please post it so we can see the context...

Comment: Most probably the LCD is not refreshed until you hit 'Enter'. More details can be given when you post the code.

Comment: The code is now available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses the built-in function `input` which only receives input when you press enter, it doesn't (and can't) read every keystroke.

You could use the [inputs](https://pypi.org/project/inputs/) or [evdev](https://pypi.org/project/evdev/) libraries to track keystrokes and act immediately upon a key being pressed, rather than waiting for the whole string to be entered.